# Change the date to the timestamp like sql

Tags: php, datetime

I want to change the date format to the timestamp to save in MySQL.

Now I have a data '2018-03-31 20:07:56'.

```
$db_timestamp = '2018-03-31 20:07:56';
```

And I can use the strtotime function to get back time

```
$str_date = strtotime($db_timestamp)
date("m-d-Y", $str_date)
```

Output: 03-31-2018

But now my problem is I have this '03-31-2018' as my initial data.

```
$date = '03-31-2018'
```

And I want to get back to '2018-03-31 00:00:00' as result.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We aren't going to be able to get the time value (`20:07:56`) back out of a string that has only year, month and day.

There's no way to get from

```
03-31-2018
```

back into

```
2018-03-31 20:07:56
```

Maybe we want to preserve the original hours, minutes, seconds value, or the entire original string.

Comment: How about if i change to 2018-03-31 00:00:00?

Comment: Maybe PHP `date_create_from_format` function? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

If you save the date as `'2018-03-31 20:07:56'` in the database. It will return same value.

Pass hour, minute, and second in date function.

```
$str_date = strtotime($db_timestamp);
```

$str_date has same value as `'2018-03-31 20:07:56'`

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $str_date);
```

We can get by passing `H:i:s` in date function,

**output:**

```
2018-03-31 20:07:56
```

Comment: Thanks, @LawrenceCherone, For hour 'H' and minute 'i'

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the underlying data in mysql. Use the format function as shown below.

First it converts datetime string to a Datetime object in php and then converts to the required format.  From Datetime object you can convert into any other format.

```
$db_timestamp = '2018-03-31 20:07:56';
$mytime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$db_timestamp);
echo $mytime ->format('m-d-Y'); // shows  03-31-2018
echo $mytime ->format('d-m-Y'); // shows  31-03-2018
echo $mytime ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // shows  2018-03-31 20:07:56
```